# Apache2 SSL "SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG"

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache2

I need help to check SSL implementation.

### Informations :

- Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
- Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
- OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019

### Verifications checked :

- a2ensite,
- a2enmod,
- apache2ctl configtest

### Configurations files :

- online.myurl.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /path/to/my/dir/html/online
    ServerName online.myurl.com

    <IfModule mod_php.c>
        php_value max_execution_time 500
        php_value max_input_time 120
        php_value memory_limit 512M
        php_value post_max_size 40M
        php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
        php_value default_socket_timeout 120
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://online.myurl.com [R=301,L]

    <Directory /path/to/my/dir/html/online>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /path/to/my/dir/html/online/upload/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /path/to/my/dir//logs/%Y-%m/online/online.myurl.com_access-%Y-%m-%d.log" vhost_combined_time_end
    ErrorLog  "|/usr/bin/cronolog /path/to/my/dir//logs/%Y-%m/online/online.myurl.com_error-%Y-%m-%d.log"

</VirtualHost>



<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>

        DocumentRoot /path/to/my/dir/html/online
        ServerName online.myurl.com

        <IfModule mod_php.c>
            php_value max_execution_time 500
            php_value max_input_time 120
            php_value memory_limit 256M
            php_value post_max_size 40M
            php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
            php_value default_socket_timeout 120
            php_value suhosin.memory_limit 1024M
        </IfModule>

        <Directory /path/to/my/dir/html/online>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /path/to/my/dir/html/online/upload/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        RewriteEngine On

        CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /path/to/my/dir//logs/%Y-%m/online/online.myurl.com_access-%Y-%m-%d.log" vhost_combined_time_end
        ErrorLog  "|/usr/bin/cronolog /path/to/my/dir//logs/%Y-%m/online/online.myurl.com_error-%Y-%m-%d.log"

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/the/certs/certificate-860128.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/the/certs/wilcard.myurl.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/the/certs/GandiStandardSSLCA2.pem

        SSLProtocol         all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

        SSLCipherSuite      ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on
        SSLCompression      off
        SSLSessionTickets   off

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

         BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

- apache2ctl -S

```
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.1:80           localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server adminclt2.myurl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/003_admin.myurl.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost adminclt2.myurl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/003_admin.myurl.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost ns61031277.ip-54-38-67.eu (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/004_vip_api.myurl.com.conf:1)
                 alias vip_api.myurl.com
         port 80 namevhost myurl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/007_myurl.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.myurl.com
         port 80 namevhost myurl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/007_myurl.com.conf:20)
         port 80 namevhost privatevisit.myurl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/008_privatevisit.myurl.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost ns61031277.ip-54-38-67.eu (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/009_vip_site.myurl.com.conf:1)
                 alias vip_site.myurl.com
                 alias lafayetteanticipation.myurl.com
         port 80 namevhost default (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/011_sites.myurl.com.conf:1)
                 wild alias *.myurl.com
                 wild alias *
         port 80 namevhost appsomething.myurl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/appsomething.myurl.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost dev.someurl.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.someurl.net.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost online.myurl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/online.myurl.com.conf:1)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server adminclt2.myurl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/003_admin.myurl.com.conf:58)
         port 443 namevhost adminclt2.myurl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/003_admin.myurl.com.conf:58)
         port 443 namevhost myurl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/007_myurl.com.conf:26)
                 alias www.myurl.com
         port 443 namevhost appsomething.myurl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/appsomething.myurl.com.conf:15)
         port 443 namevhost ns61031277.ip-54-38-67.eu (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost dev.someurl.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.someurl.net.conf:15)
         port 443 namevhost online.myurl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/online.myurl.com.conf:42)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex fcgid-proctbl: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex fcgid-pipe: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Have you got any idea or need additionals informations ?

Thanks

EDIT : All my configs were OK but it was necessary to launch a simple linux command :

c_rehash /path/to/the/certs/

Comment: This message typically occurs when trying to access something which is not HTTPS with HTTPS. It is unknown what you are trying to access. Also look into the error files of your server.

Comment: My certs are ok and vhost conf file seems ok... How can I debug Apache2 SSL process ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming in : if you have mod_ssl enabled, open ports, and Apache keeps trying to send HTTP over HTTPS; double check your enabled websites and remember SSL implementation.

SSL checks connection [BEFORE] checking domain, and Apache check by domain alphabetically. So if you have two websites

app.website.com
[www.website.com](http://www.website.com)

... and your app.website.com is misconfigured, it will show you an error, although [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) config may be just fine.

I had a app.website.com opened on 443 without certificate, and [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) was still rejecting but certificates were valids. Just disabling app.website.com on 443 did the trick.

Comment: Same problem here. I fixed it adding one self-signed cert to the site which didn't had the `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` directives.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions [here](https://techexpert.tips/apache/enable-https-apache/) solved my problem within 5 minutes using a freshly built apache2 server on Debian Buster amd64