# Validate a self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, webserver

I created a self-signed SSL certificate for my Apache server on Debian 10, it is working, I can access the link with https:// but it displays a message of not secure, I would like to know if there is any way I can validate it .

My Apache is working on port 3 as unfortunately I can't use the default 80, I had to change the 000-default.conf file so that SSL works on a port other than 443 and 80.

I tried using the [SSLLABS](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) tool but unfortunately it didn't work because of port 3.

Does anyone know any way to validate a certificate on a different port?

In case you need it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70710271/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-when-configuring-apache-ssl/70717756#70717756) has more information about my apache.

Comment: Because it's a self-signed certificate it needs to be explicitly trusted on every client. The procedure to trust is different for different browsers and OSes. But it usually starts with opening the certificate in the browser.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the title is not written in English. Most users here only speak English and won't be able to understand your question when parts of it are in other languages. Please [edit] your post to translate all of it into English.

Comment: Title changed, forgot to translate, sorry